# React Native cannot change button colors

Tags: react-native, button, colors

I am studying react native "bar" developing an app. I am not designing the fine details of the app. But I would like to change the button color at least I've tried this.

```
   <Button style={{    backgroundColor: 'black'}} onPress={() => regiao()} title="Entrar">       </Button>
```

And several other things, but the hole button is always blue.

Answer (score 1):

Color is a separate variable in your component, do this:

```
   <Button color='black' onPress={() => regiao()} title="Entrar">       </Button>
```

See: https://reactnative.dev/docs/button

To change the text color to red:

```
<Button style={{color:'red'}} color='black' onPress={() => regiao()} title="Entrar">       </Button>
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the text color of the button?

Answer (score 0):

Do that:
`<Button color='black'></Button>`

Without style.